# Return an image from endpoint in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, endpoint, sveltekit

I have a sveltekit endpoint that pulls an svg image, converts it into Uint8Array and returns it. After a recent update of sveltekit the endpoint is no longer returning an image. Is there anything I am missing?

```
 // convert svg to png using sharp
    const response = await axios(request); // this contains the svg data
    skullData = response.data;
    const png = await svg2png(
        skullData.image_data,
        {
            scale: 1, // optional
            width: 512, // optional
            height: 512, // optional
            backgroundColor: 'white', // optional
        },
    );
    return {
        body: png
    };
```

To make things more obscure this is working locally, but not anymore when deployed to netlify.

Comment: You might need to put a content type to your return: `"Content-Type": "image/png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably fixed by this related SvelteKit issue: [Serving images from endpoint routes no longer possible](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1438)

I guess SvelteKit was messing up the content-type headers for binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Vercel to deploy your app, it worked for me. Quite odd cause it used to work alright with Netlify. Probably some changes on the past month on either side made endpoints fail to properly send images back to the client pages.

Also, the "Content-Type" header might help as Stephane mentioned.